# How do I redirect only the root domain using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I installed a self hosted URL shortener to my mydomain.co
If i enter into a browser example.co or http://www.example.co (with and without trailing /), I see the file and folder list for the domain.

Since I have a URL Shortener installed (Yourls is the program) for everything after the domain name would be a valid link (ie http://example.co/myshortlink and should redirect) , but if someone enters just the domain name, I would like to redirect to another page or load a index.html file and not list my files/folders that would be under just the root domain.

Please help.
Thank you for taking the time to answer.
James

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an `index.html` file in the root folder. Once one enters your root folder, the index.html will be automatically displayed, because the `index.[php|html|htm]` file is the default file which which will be loaded.

To suppress directory listing, add `Options -Indexes` to your `.htaccess`.

To redirect to another website, create an `index.php` file in your root folder with the contents:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://example.com/a/b/c">`

Where `http://example.com/a/b/c` is the URL you want to redirect to.